# How to style tabItem using nativescript angular and theme builder?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I created Nativescript Angular app using tab navigation template. This template created following `app.component.html`:

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom" class="tab-view">

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'People', iconSource: getIconSource('home')}"
        name="homeTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Events', iconSource: getIconSource('search')}"
        name="browseTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

    <page-router-outlet
        *tabItem="{title: 'Tags', iconSource: getIconSource('browse')}"
        name="searchTab">
    </page-router-outlet>

</TabView>
```

I created `.css` file using theme builder at https://www.nativescriptthemebuilder.com/ which produced this part:

```
.tab-view {
    selected-tab-text-color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-view {
    tab-text-color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-view {
    tab-background-color: #823551;
}

.tab-view {
    android-selected-tab-highlight-color: #d6c7d1;
}
```

There was instruction to add CSS classes to native element so I added `tab-view` class as you can see in first snippet. But text color of a tab, and text color of selected tab is not changed and is not matching the color from theme builder. All examples I've found are for `xml` views or not using `*tabItem` directive.

So either Nativescript's theme builder doesn't work with Nativescript's own app template or I'm doing something wrong. Did I forget or missed something in this configuration?

Comment: Which platform you are currently testing this on?

Comment: @Manoj I'm testing it on Android. I've just found `_app-variables.scss` and will play with colors there. Maybe they override template styles.

Comment: The tabbed template use `scss` files and template generator creates `css`. So what I did was just changing extension to `scss` and including it in `app.android.scss`. Some styles were applied but some not. For example page title is also not changed to right color.